# C# Equals SQLServer select xml.nodes in Oracle to serealize

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, xmlserializer

Is there something equivalent in Oracle for these cases?

select NickName, 
      ExternalId1 from Basics 
      where externalId1 = @externalId1   **for xml auto**, **elements**;

and this

```
select
 x.n.value('OperationId[1]', 'int'),
 x.n.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
 x.n.value('MaxTime[1]', 'float')
from @xml.nodes('/*[1]') x(n);
```

I want to implement something generic like this but in Oracle.

Thanks.

Comment: Read the Oracle [XML DB Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16659/toc.htm)

Comment: thanks! i will read this..